# React test fails with react-hook-media-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using [react-hook-media-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/media-query) in my project but the test is failing because of it.
This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import useMediaQuery from 'react-hook-media-query';


const MyCompp = (props) => {
  const minWidth1200 = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1200px)');
  ...
}
```

test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { WrapIntlProvider, WrapStore } from '../testsHelper';

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
  useSelector: () => ({
    locale: 'en-US',
    messages: {}
  })
}));

describe('<App />', function () {
  it('should render <App />', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <WrapStore>
        <WrapIntlProvider>
          <App />
        </WrapIntlProvider>
      </WrapStore>
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

and when I run the tests it throws this error message:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>
> Here's what you can do:
>  • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
>  • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
>  • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>  • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config
> ```
>
> option.
> You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
>
> ```
> Details:
>
> /.../node_modules/react-hook-media-query/dist/index.js:1
> ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import
> ```
>
> { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
> ^^^^^^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>
> > 2 | import useMediaQuery from 'react-hook-media-query';
>     | ^
> ```

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Could you solve it? Seems like you are importing the wrong library, should be ```import { useMediaQueries } from '@react-hook/media-query';```

Comment: And for some reason, ```import``` is not working in your code, try using the nodejs approach with ```const { useMediaQueries } = require('@react-hook/media-query');```